# SSL issue - too many redirects

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

The website in question is: *sophostechnologies.com*

https://sophostechnologies.com or sophostechnologies.com works fine and loads in SSL, HOWEVER, if I type www. or https://www. in front of the url name, I get too many redirects loop error.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sophostechnologies.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# Google sitemap controller
RewriteRule ^(tmp/)?sitemap.xml$ tmp/sitemap.xml [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.php([0-9]*)|\.json|\.xml|\.tpl|\.phtml|\.ini|\.inc|/)$ index.php?_p=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any help is appreciated.